# How to implement a reverse proxy for one subdomain

Tags: reverse-proxy

I have a set of servers behind a firewall.  It only supports port forwarding.  So far all my subdomains (www., server., beta., cloud.) are all on one server (OS X Server).

I also have a dev. subdomain that is on a separate Freebsd server. form my internal network i can use my DNS to send traffic to the correct server for the dev. subdomain.  but when i access from outside i cannot get to the dev server via port 80 as that port is forwarded to the main server.

Rather than using a none standard port I would like to reverse proxy back to the dev server from my main server but it looks like this is for URL's not for subdomains.  Is there a way i can route all requests for dev.example.com to the internal development server via my main server.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's a standard use case for all common rproxies, and you'll find almost ready to use examples in their respective documentations. With nginx the basic setup will look like this (put this a file in the enabled-sites subdirectory):

```
server {
    # prod marked as default so lost traffic ends up on production
    listen 192.168.0.1:80 default;
    server_name production.your.domain;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/production-access.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://your.production.server:80;
    }
}

server {
    listen 192.168.0.1:80;
    server_name dev.your.domain;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/development-access.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://your.development.server:80;
    }
}
```

With Pound you could use something like

```
Service
  HeadRequire "Host: .*production.your.domain.*"
  BackEnd
    Address your.production.server
    Port    80
  End
End

Service
  HeadRequire "Host: .*dev.your.domain.*"
  BackEnd
    Address your.development.server
    Port    80
  End
End

# and a safety net for lost traffic
Service
  URL "/"
  Redirect "http://production.you.domain"
end;
```

---

Apache's mod_proxy is also possible, but due to lack of hands on experience with that combo I had to borrow an example from an [Atlassian documentation webpage](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Using+Apache+with+virtual+hosts+and+mod_proxy):

```
# Put this after the other LoadModule directives
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so

# Put this with your other VirtualHosts, or at the bottom of the file
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName confluence.example.com

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://confluence-app-server.internal.example.com:8090/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://confluence-app-server.internal.example.com:8090/
    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName jira.example.com

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://jira-app-server.internal.example.com:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://jira-app-server.internal.example.com:8080/
    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: @MB see edit - note that the former two are derived from configs I have running (so I'm pretty confident that they'll do what I claim them to do, the Apache same was borrowed from an external documentation site, and although it looks quite OK, I cannot guarantee its correctness.